# Find the value of $x$ if $x^{x^4} =4$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponentiation

Find the value of $x$ if $x^{x^4}=4$. Given options are

1. $2^{1/2}$
2. $-2^{1/2} $
3. Both 1. & 2
4. None of the above

From option verification, we get option 3. as correct one. But is there any real method to do the above problem?

Comment: Can you show any working out you have done?

Comment: Can you tell us more about the level where this came from? Given that it looks like multiple choice it is very much possible that it was designed to simply test the students' A) grasp of the definition of powers, B) ability to eliminate wrong alternatives in a multiple choice setting. For example, proving that no other solutions exist may be asking a bit much on some levels. Also I'm a bit worried about apparently allowing $x<0$. At precalculus levels fractional powers of negative numbers are a bit troubling. Here we happen to get an integer exponent, but if we are to find all solutions...?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen If we let $x=-2^{\frac 1 2}=-\sqrt 2$, then $x^4=4$ and thus $x^{x^4}=(-\sqrt 2)^4$, which is not troubling at all in pre-calculus. At least in my pre-calc class, we would probably be expected to realize that there are both positive and negative solutions because of the possible even power that could be $x^4$.

Comment: I know @NobleMushtak. That was part of my point. But how would a precalculus student prove that there are no other solutions?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Oh...Good point. EDIT: According to Wolfram Alpha, $\pm \sqrt 2$ are [not the only solutions](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E(x%5E4)%3D4).

Comment: Perhaps noting that $x^4\ln x=\ln4$ would be helpful? Also, it is worth noting that Noble Mushtak's link shows that *Wolfram Alpha*, which is optimized for symbolic manipulation, found the solution numerically.

Comment: Since you are given choices, putting the putative solutions into the equation to see whether or not they satisfy the equation **is** a "real method" of solving the problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no systematic way of solving such transcendental equations. In this particular case, we can get better insight by performing a transformation to get rid of the double exponentiation.

$$4=x^{x^4}=(x^4)^{x^4/4}=t^{t/4}.$$

Then

$$t^t=4^4$$ and an obvious solution is $t=4$ corresponding to $x=\pm\sqrt2$.

By the study of the function $t^t$, we can verify that it is increasing where it exceeds $1$, so that the above solution is unique.

Answer (score 3):

$x\in\mathbb{R}$

$(x^{-4})^{x^4}=4^{-4}$ => $x^{-4}=4^{-1}$ => $x^4=4$ => $x=\pm\sqrt{2}$

EDIT:

*Jyrki Lahtonen* gave me the advise to carry out the proof accurately.

Therefore: $x^{x^4}=4$ , $(z;a):=(x^{-4};\frac{1}{4})$ => $z^{\frac{1}{z}}=a^{\frac{1}{a}}$

We have $0<a^{\frac{1}{a}}<1$ therefore we have only one positive solution $z=a$.

This means $x^4=4$ and therefore $x=\pm\sqrt{2}$.

EDIT 2:

$x^\frac{1}{x}$ is strictly increasing (therefore bijective) for $0<x<e$ because of 
$(x^\frac{1}{x})’=x^{(-2+\frac{1}{x})}(1-\ln x)>0$.

Comment: I haven't had the time to downvote yet, but how do you justify the first implication?

Comment: It's the compare of $a^\frac{1}{a}=b^\frac{1}{b}$ and the fact, that we have only one solution for $y=x^\frac{1}{x}$ when $0<y<1$.

Comment: I see. It might be a good idea to include a proof of that (it does work).

Comment: I meant that you would include a proof of the key result that when $0<x<1$ there is only one positive $y$ such that $x=y^{1/y}$.

Comment: I have completed the arguments.

Answer (score 2):

You already know how to verify the options here, but you're asking for a way to solve this equation step-by-step. The issue is that there is no way to find a closed form solution for $x$ using elementary functions. The solution is only expressible using a special function known as the Lambert W. This function is the inverse of the function $f(x) = xe^x$. You can read more about it [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function).

There are two ways to handle this "from first principles".

The first, which has already been covered by @user90369, is to find solutions by observation (which means inspired guess and check, really), then prove rigorously that no other solutions can exist.

The second is to find a direct solution using the Lambert W.

We start by simplifying the form of the equation with the substitution $x = y^{\frac 14}$

After some elementary simplification, you will end up with $y^y= 256$. This is, of course, very amenable to a solution "by inspection", but let's proceed as originally intended.

$$y^y = 256$$

$$e^{\ln y e^{\ln y}} = 256$$

$$\ln y e^{\ln y} = \ln 256$$

$$\ln y = W(\ln 256)$$

$$y = e^{W(\ln 256)} = \frac{\ln 256}{W(\ln 256)}$$

where a property of the Lambert W is used for the final step.

At this point, you have to use a special calculator or mathematical software to find out the value of $W(\ln 256)$. One such calculator is [here](http://www.had2know.com/academics/lambert-w-function-calculator.html).

Using that, we can do the calculation to find that $y$ is very close to $4$. We can now make an "inspired guess" that it *is* $4$ since no more exact calculation is available to us. We find that it works, so we accept the solution (you should know how to find $x$ after determining $y$).

Comment: Certainly, the Lambert W function should not be used on a multiple choice precalculus question.

Comment: @MarkMcClure Of course, I know that. This question obviously asks for a simple solution verification, no more. But the OP wanted to know how to find a "real method", which I interpreted to mean a solution from first principles, and which is what I provided.

Comment: +1 for understanding the request, acknowledging it was outside the scope of the original question, and handling it like a pro anyway. What a great answer.

Comment: @Deepak: You use a sledgehammer to crack a nut. :-)

Comment: @user90369: not necessarily. It is true that a solution can be found by inspection, but the case of, say $x^{x^4}=5$ would be a different story. And making sure to exhaust the solutions requires some care.

Comment: @user90369 True, but the OP asked for a sledgehammer solution! :) So even though this nut can be cracked open easily with a simple nutcracker, he wanted a more general purpose tool that can be used for even tougher nuts. And I'll stop now, I think this metaphor is tortured enough as it is. :)

Comment: @Yves Daoust: Then he would have asked about a general solution - but he hasn't. The author wants to have a real method - to use Lambert is a solution replacement.

Comment: @Deepak: The method "Lambert" is wellknown - but not the only possible one, also not the only sledgehammer solution. However: I thought, the author wanted to have the most simply way - but o.k., I thought wrong.

Comment: @user90369: you can attach to the qualifier "real" the meaning that pleases you. Equations with the unknown on different exponent levels calls for "Lambertian" analysis.

Comment: I have downvoted this due to one and only one reason. Since I'm a school student, I shouldn't use scientific calculators while doing the problems.

Comment: @saisaandeep No prob, thank you for being honest about downvoting and giving your reason - I am on a mini-crusade (haha) to improve transparency in voting.  Anyway, a few points in reply : 1) if you have stipulations,  you should state them clearly. Not every school system is the same, and my son could use a scientific calc from the age of 9. 2) be clearer with your terminology - "real method" is difficult to decipher  3) finally, accept that trying to figure out a more general solution than the setter likely wanted may end up requiring more resources than that elementary setting permits.

Comment: @Deepak Now that is a fine example of being "nicer to downvoters"!

Comment: @MarkMcClure My apologies in advance if I have misconstrued your intent, but was that sarcasm? It's tough to tell.

Comment: @Deepak Sorry for the confusion - I meant the comment to be genuine. I noticed your participation in the [can we be nicer to downvoters thread](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/23486/) so I thought I would point out that you are being quite genuinely nice to a downvoter.

Comment: @MarkMcClure Ah, thanks very much for the compliment and my apologies (again) for being in a little doubt, it's tough to tell via text messages. I figured it's best to lead by example, if anyone leaves a comment constructively explaining a downvote (behaviour we should encourage), the least we can do is to be civil in return. In fact, I wanted to be even gentler in my reply, but character limits dictate terseness as you know. Anyway, appreciate it mate. :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is rigorous, but you could notice that because $4=x^{x^4}$, we can write 
$$4=x^{x^4}=x^{x^{x^{x^4}}}$$
and so on, until we get a stack of $x$'s equalling to $4$:
$$x^{x^{x^{x^{.^{.^{.}}}}}}=4$$
And so 
$$x^4=4$$ 
which yields $x=\pm\sqrt 2$

Answer (score 0):

$x^{x^4}=4$
First of all, we think simple.
$x^{x^4}=2^{2^1}$
We did that because we have to make first two steps equal$x$
Later we have to make our third step in our second equation ,4 .
$$x^{x^4}=2^(2^(1/4))^4$$
$$x^x=2^{2^{1/4}}$$
We have simplified our problem. Now we should make both steps equal in our second equation. If we take the square of our power number (to make sure they are equal), we must take the square root of our number. Therefore:

$2^{2^{1/4}}= 2^{{1/2}^{2^{1/2}}}$
Our previous power $4$ was even. 
Solutions are $-2^{1/2}$ and $2^{1/2}$.

Comment: First of all: *please* use MathJax.

Comment: Sorry for that. I am answering via my phone.